# Infinite scroll duplicates rows

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I'm using [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) dependency for my angularjs project.

Whenever I scroll up and down again, it duplicates the rows.

HTML

```
<table infinite-scroll="loadMore()" ng-controller="LastBookingsCtrl">
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
$http.get("last.php?start=" + $scope.currentLoadIndex)
    .then(function (res) {
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
            var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.lastBookings.push(res.data[i]);
                    count++;
                }
            $scope.currentLoadIndex += count;
        }
    });
};
```

PHP

```
$start = $_GET['start'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `performs` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 20";
```

Comment: A bit unrelated to your question, but please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: It's fixed. Sorry for posting this, can be removed.

Comment: @enucar What was the issue if you don't mind sharing? It could be helpful for someone. Also, you should consider securing your query against SQL injection like Skwal mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting the same result each time because you `$scope.currentLoadIndex` is not updating correctly from the `then()`. Try setting the next index to the length of the current list aka:

`$http.get("last.php?start=" + $scope.lastBookings.length)`